# How to add style to a new element and remove it on its creation

Tags: javascript, html, css, ajax

i have an javascript code, which is create new element on button click and i have a question.
Here is my javascript code:

```
var comment = document.querySelector("#AddComment");
var req = new XMLHttpRequest();

if(comment){
    comment.addEventListener("click", function () {
        var csrftok = '{{ csrf_token }}';
        req.open('POST', '{{ request.path }}');
        CommentBlock = {
            "text": comment.previousElementSibling.value,
            //'csrfmiddlewaretoken': csrftok,
        };
        req.setRequestHeader('X-CSRFToken', csrftok);
        req.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
        req.onreadystatechange = function () {
            if(req.readyState == 4) {
                let text = document.createElement('div');
                text.innerHTML = req.responseText;
                let comment_blocks = text.querySelector("#comments").getElementsByClassName("commentblock");
                let new_block = comment_blocks[comment_blocks.length - 1];
                document.querySelector("#comment_addform").before(new_block);
            };
        };
        req.send(JSON.stringify(CommentBlock));
    });
}
```

How can i add to this new element a style, which would play only once, on its creation, and removing this style when this element is created and this style not needed anymore.

UPD. My html code:

```
<div class="jumbotron col-md-7 col-md-push-2" id="comments" data-aos="fade-up">
{% for comment in post.comments.all %}
    {% if comment.is_parent %}
    <div class="commentblock">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-2 col-md-2">
                <div class="thumbnail">
                    <img class="img-responsive user-photo" src="{{ comment.author.profile.image.url }}">
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-sm-9 col-md-10">
                <div class="panel panel-default">
                    <div class="panel-heading">
                        <strong>{{ comment.author }}</strong> {# <span class="text-muted">commented 5 days ago</span> #}
                    </div>
                    <div class="panel-body">
                        {{ comment.text }}
                    </div>
                    <div class="panel-footer" id="answers_{{ comment.id }}">
                        {% for child in comment.children %}
                            <div class="answerblock">
                                <div class="row col-md-push-1">
                                    <div class="col-sm-2 col-md-2">
                                        <div class="thumbnail">
                                            <img class="img-responsive user-photo" src="{{ child.author.profile.image.url }}">
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-sm-10 col-md-10">
                                        <div class="panel panel-default">
                                            <div class="panel-heading">
                                                <strong>{{ child.author }}</strong> {# <span class="text-muted">commented 5 days ago</span> #}
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="panel-body">
                                                {{ child.text }}
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        {% endfor %}
                        <form method="post" id="answer_addform_{{ comment.id }}">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                {% csrf_token %}
                                <input type="hidden" name="parent_id" value="{{ comment.id }}">
                                {{ comment_form.text|add_class:'form-control'|attr:'cols:'|attr:'rows:' }}
                                <input type="reset" class="btn btn-sm btn-block AddAnswer" onclick="sendreqfor_answer(this)" value="Ответить"/>
                            </div>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: post html code too

Comment: Okey, i posted it

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly your best option would be to use CSS animations.

I'm not sure what element you are trying to animate, but let's say that element has "commentblock" class. If you want to make fade-in animation then your CSS code might look like this:

```
.commentblock {
    animation: custom 1s;
}

@keyframes custom {
    0% {
        display: block;
        opacity: 0;
    }
    100% {
        opacity: 1;
    }
}
```

You can find more details here: https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_animations.asp